# Popup session timeout message on windows authentication mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, session-cookies

I'm working in project that i have to use windows authentication for authenticating and authorizing users (this first time for me to use windows authentication),i successfully deployed my application in IIS and it totally works fine.

I have little inquire i want to know about:

how to show popup message when session timeout occur?

any one help please.
thanks

Comment: Ok sorry for confusing you and for asking (so) question but I asked after doing a lot of search.

Comment: If it solved before please provide me with link

Comment: Type in Google as - site:http://stackoverflow.com asp.net session timeout popup